# Material UI V1-beta Create-React App

Tags: javascript, npm, material-ui, create-react-app

Ich habe soeben das Create React App example from Material-UI.com installiert.

```
curl https://codeload.github.com/callemall/material-ui/tar.gz/v1-beta | tar -xz --strip=2 material-ui-1-beta/examples/create-react-app
```

I get this error messages:

```
npm WARN react-popper@0.7.3 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-popper@0.7.3 requires a peer of react-dom@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-scrollbar-size@2.0.1 requires a peer of react@^15.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

This is a peace from the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "jss": "latest",
    "jss-preset-default": "latest",
    "material-ui": "next",
    "material-ui-icons": "latest",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-jss": "latest",
    "react-scripts": "latest",
    "recompose": "latest",
    "typeface-roboto": "latest"
  },
```

How do I install the peer dependencies right?

After run npm start I get 10 error messages like this:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `jss` of type `Jss` supplied to `JssProvider`, expected instance of `Jss`.
    in JssProvider (at withRoot.js:41)
    in withRoot(withStyles(Index)) (at index.js:8)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ proxyConsole.js:54
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the jss stuff in the package.json.
2. Downgrade to React 15.62 and react-dom 15.6.2

`"dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "next",
    "material-ui-icons": "latest",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "latest",
    "recompose": "latest",
    "typeface-roboto": "latest"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

to add to @joerg,  do not forget to delete node_modules and package-lock.json to remove completely JSS